# Error when I use Open Office API in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, openoffice-writer

I use an Open Office API in my ASP .NET application for reading text content from *.doc files.

```
public static bool getTextV2(string siteURL, string[] search)
{
    //Create a new ServiceManager Type object
    Type tServiceManager = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("com.sun.star.ServiceManager", true);
    //Create a new ServiceManager Com object using our
    //ServiceManager type object
    object oServiceManager = System.Activator.CreateInstance(tServiceManager);
    //Create our Desktop Com object
    object oDesktop = Invoke(oServiceManager, "createinstance",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
    //Create an array for our load parameter
    Object[] arg = new Object[4];
    arg[0] = siteURL;
    arg[1] = "_blank";
    arg[2] = 0;
    arg[3] = new Object[] { };
    //Create our new blank document
    object oComponent = Invoke(oDesktop,
    "loadComponentFromUrl",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    arg
    );
    //Create an empty array for the getText method
    arg = new Object[0];
    //Get our Text Com object
    Object oText = Invoke(oComponent,
    "getText",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    arg
    );
    Object Text = Invoke(oText,
    "getString",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    arg
    );
    string content = Text.ToString();
    content = content.ToLower();
    bool flag = true;
    foreach (string current in search)
    {
        if (!content.Contains(current)) flag = false;
    }
    arg = new Object[0];
    Invoke(oComponent,
    "dispose",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    arg
    );

    return flag;
}
public static object Invoke(object obj, string method, BindingFlags binding, params object[] par)
{
    return obj.GetType().InvokeMember(method, binding, null, obj, par);
}
```

But I have the following error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {82154420-0FBF-11D4-8313-005004526AB4} failed due to the following error: 80080005.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {82154420-0FBF-11D4-8313-005004526AB4} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 56: //Create a new ServiceManager Com object using our
Line 57: //ServiceManager type object
Line 58: object oServiceManager = System.Activator.CreateInstance(tServiceManager);
Line 59: //Create our Desktop Com object
Line 60: object oDesktop = Invoke(oServiceManager, "createinstance",
```

So, there is a error at line 58.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure OO.o is very efficient for text extraction.  You might be interested in an article on text extraction from MS Word documents using just built in Indexing service here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilter.aspx

Comment: I have build solution for doc to html convertion with OpenOffice and it is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Quick guess: could it be that user under which your are running app never opened OpenOffice before. Try login as that user and run OpenOffice it will ask few questions, then close OpenOffice and logout. Then try to run your app again....